# How to configure robots.txt to disallow any URL/file/directory with a certain word in it?

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, robots.txt, technical-seo

I've seen basic articles online about allowing/disallowing certain subdirectories in `robots.txt`, but I have a more detailed need than that.

Google search console keeps trying to discover/crawl certain URLs on my site that it shouldn't be doing. It's not a security hazard, but essentially what it's crawling are completely redundant URLs that don't exist in actuality. I have an idea of why it's happening, but I don't want to try and restructure my pages to accommodate Google in this regard.

These unnecessary page crawls always contain a certain phrase in the URL. Suppose this phrase is "unnecessaryPage", as in `info-unnecessaryPage.htm` is a URL that Google attempts to crawl, and I don't want it to.

How can I create a "disallow" line to do this? For example, if I wanted to disallow an entire directory, I'd put this:

```
Disallow: /DirectoryA
```

But I want to disallow everything that includes the phrase "unnecessaryPage" anywhere in the filename, directory, or URL. How would I make that Disallow line?

Comment: Are these links originating from outside?  Or is it possible that there is a bug in your code and some of your pages are generating this url as a link?  There are many website checking sites that will rule-out/confirm the latter.  One such one is ahrefs.com.  I am not affiliated with it, but I do use it.

Comment: These links are actually in my code now that I've looked at them again, but they're paramater style links with "?"and parameters passed after the question mark.

So, it's not a bug, but I don't want google trying to comb thousands of copies of the same page.

Comment: Adding a query string to the URL makes a new URL. Google has to crawl all the different query strings it finds because it doesn't know whether or not there's going to be different content when the query string is different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The directive would be something like this:

```
user-agent: *
disallow: /*unnecessaryPage
```

Thus, anything that comes before the phrase "unnecessaryPage" will be included via wildcard. No trailing wildcard: it is optional because it is ignored. Further examples can be found in [Google's documentation](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/robots/robots_txt) on the matter.

Comment: I'd add the caveat at any time you use wild cards in a disallow rule, that rule will only be understood by major search engine bots including googlebot. Most bots are not advanced enough to understand the wild card syntax.

Comment: Thanks, this matches up with an article I found over the weekend:

https://geoffkenyon.com/how-to-use-wildcards-robots-txt/

Down at the bottom they also link to a useful syntax tester tool from google.

Answer (score 2):

In my view the accepted answer is insufficient.  The robots rule will stop Google from **crawling** these URLs.  But it will not stop it from **indexing** them.

To stop Google from indexing them,

1. they should either produce a **404**, or
2. they should **not exist** in any other page or
3. the links must have **noindex**.

Even then, if an external site links to them, then they may still get indexed

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Google won't usually index URLs that are blocked in robots.txt. It sometimes does if there are enough external links pointing to them. If you're using query parameters for tracking there can be enough variation that having them all crawled could be problematic for crawl budget. If there are a small number of these URLs and the goal is to not have them indexed, then I agree with you that allowing them to be crawled but then using a no index tag would be better.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - I didnt intend to imply that robots entry was unnecessary.  I meant it was insufficient.  In this case, Google has already indexed them.

Comment: If you use a noindex tag, then you actually need to remove the disallow from robots.txt or Googlebot will never crawl the URLs and see the tag.  It is an either/or proposition.  Using both is the same as just using robots.txt.